# Why am I seeing Device Support Update notification?

Tags: catalina, software-update, notifications

[image: Notification]

I am on 10.15.7 and the *device support update* keeps showing up on my Notifications at 21:59 and lasts for a minute *as per* my *Do Not Disturb* settings. I have no interest in downloading 200MB for mobile devices that I am never going to have. I have Software Update set to **not** automatically keep my Mac up to date and **not** automatically check for updates in the Advanced, but it seems to ignore that. Is there any way I can dismiss this?

[image: Software Update]

Edit: I unchecked the "Install system data files and security updates" by enabling "Check for updates" and then disabling. The UI behaved as excepted and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: "Install system data files and security updates" is selected, could you try unchecking it? (from the macOS help, this option causes "your Mac [to] install system files and security updates automatically.")

Comment: It was worth a try, but that seems to have no effect.